# Django with Graphos using csv

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

Iam trying to use Graphos with my Django html template to grab data from csv, and display a graph. I tried from the documentation https://pypi.org/project/django-graphos/, but the template isnt showing anything.

In my views i did this

```
from graphos.sources.csv_file import CSVDataSource
def graphos_chart(request):
    csv_file = open("order_dashboard/Book1.csv")
    data_source = CSVDataSource(csv_file)
    return render(request, 'order_dashboard/home.html', {'chart': data_source})
```

template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
</script>

{{ data_source|safe }}
```

Book1.csv

```
,January,February,March,April,May,June,July
Temperature,7,7,10,15,20,23,26
Precipitation,8.1,14.9,41.0,31.4,42.6,57.5,36.0
```

Something is missing in above method?
Or please suggest any alternate Graph plotting library to look for.